# Is prepare-agent goal is necessary in jacoco-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

In My project, if I write pom like this:

```
...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
            <executions> 
                <execution>  
                  <id>post-test</id>  
                  <phase>test</phase>  
                  <goals>  
                        <goal>report</goal>  
                  </goals>  
                </execution>  
           </executions>  

        </plugin>
...
```

it will not generate report in my project after i run mvn install.

but i change it to

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
            <executions> 
                <execution>  
                    <id>pre-test</id>  
                    <goals>  
                      <goal>prepare-agent</goal>  
                    </goals>  
                  </execution> 
                <execution>  
                  <id>post-test</id>  
                  <phase>test</phase>  
                  <goals>  
                        <goal>report</goal>  
                  </goals>  
                </execution>  
           </executions>  

        </plugin>
```

it worked!!

I want to know what was the different?

I read the offical document here: http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html

the goal prepare-agent is just for set property for jvm agent, not start jvm agent, why it is necessary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well the link shared by you over [`prepare:agent`](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html) already reads much of it:

> ```
> Prepares a property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent that can be
> passed as a VM argument to the application under test.
> ```

So if the goal is not bound to the plugin execution, then the default behavior for the property would be either `argLine` or `tycho.testArgLine` for packaging type eclipse-test-plugin.

In your case, if we assume its `argLine`, and your project defines the VM arguments for test execution, you need to make sure that they include this property.

> One of the ways to do this in case of maven-surefire-plugin - is to
>   use syntax for late property evaluation:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <argLine>@{argLine} -your -extra -arguments</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The detailed [`Java Agent`](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html) doc, can help you understand deeper how Jacoco uses its own agent to provide a *mechanism that allows in-memory pre-processing of all class files during class loading independent of the application framework.*